# How to separate text inside Textboox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, text, textbox

I have a textbox in which user can enter multiple Email Address, now since user can enter multiple address so I need something that can separate each email Address

I'm looking for something like this

[image: Sample]

The same example can be seen on stackoverflow.com when we type multiple tags

Thanks

Comment: You gotta provide more information. What are you even using? java? c? html/js/jquery?

Comment: Im using ASP.NET and jQuery

Comment: Then add the relevant tags, and add the code you've attempted.

Comment: I have added just a simple asp:textbox , now I don't know how to seperate text inside textbox

   <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several jquery components that you can use, try one of these:

- [Tag-it](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/)
- [Xoxco tagsInput](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/)
- [Tags Manager](http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager)
- [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)
- [textextjs](http://textextjs.com/)

Hope this helps.